# How to publish web site using PSAKE

Tags: asp.net, publish, psake

Is there a way to publish asp.net web application using PSAKE, just like visual studio do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Psake you have the function exec to run programs. With this task/function you can build, compile and publish your web app

You can execute asp_compiler to build you project/solution

```
Exec { aspnet_compiler.exe }
```

Refer to the msdn site for the exact syntax and parameters for the aspnet_compiler.exe

**I have found an example that show how to do it :**

http://blog.developwithpassion.com/2008/10/30/interested-in-trading-in-your-nant-builds-a-teaser/

Comment: aspnet_compiler has issues with compiling folder, not project file. But this is not an issue, but a reason to clean up project

Answer (score 5):

As per [this post](http://blog.m.jedynak.pl/2008/03/publishing-web-application-with-msbuild.html), here's another way of publishing your web application.  I've used this technique for publishing an .asmx web service.  The trick is the `_CopyWebApplication` msbuild target, which makes the distributable files for your web app.

```
# ...setup properties

task PublishWebService -depends Compile  {
    $output_dir = "$build_dir\$configuration\Web"
    $output_bin_dir = "$output_dir\bin\"
    msbuild $webservice_project_file /t:ResolveReferences /t:_CopyWebApplication /p:Configuration=$configuration /p:WebProjectOutputDir="..\$output_dir" /p:OutDir="..\$output_bin_dir"
    if (-not (Test-Path $web_service_inetpub_dir)) {
            mkdir $web_service_inetpub_dir
        }
    copy $output_dir\* -destination $web_service_inetpub_dir -recurse -force
    "Publish OK!"
}
```

See also [this post](http://www.yangq.org/2011/04/09/automate-asp-net-deployment-with-powershell-install-and-update/) for some information on setting up and tearing down IIS sites and app pools from within your psake script.

**UPDATE:**
I've found the following commands to work a bit better.  The one I posted above does not correctly apply web.config transforms.

```
# ...
msbuild /t:Rebuild /p:OutDir=..\$output_dir\ /p:Configuration=$build_configuration /p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=False /p:TrackFileAccess=false "$web_app_project_file"
# ...
copy $output_dir\_PublishedWebsites\$web_app_project_name\* -destination $inetpub_dir -recurse -force
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using build in packaging from .net 4.0 and Web Deployment Tools on IIS. Here is a snippet of code to use it from PSake:

https://gist.github.com/579086